# I am having an issue with cabal install and cannot seem to install pretty-simple

Tags: windows, haskell, ghc, cabal, cabal-install

So actually when I run install, it appears to be already installed:

```
$ cabal install pretty-simple
Resolving dependencies...
Copying 'pretty-simple.exe' to 'C:\Users\ameen\.local\bin\pretty-simple.exe'
Error: cabal.exe: Path 'C:\Users\ameen\.local\bin\pretty-simple' already
exists. Use --overwrite-policy=always to overwrite.
```

But then when I check if it is installed, it appears it isn't:

```
$ cabal list pretty-simple
* pretty-simple
    Synopsis: pretty printer for data types with a 'Show' instance.
    Default available version: 4.1.2.0
    Installed versions: [ Not installed ]
    Homepage: https://github.com/cdepillabout/pretty-simple
    License:  BSD3
```

I've tried:

adding --lib

specifying the location with cabal install pretty-simple --package-db=C:\tools\ghc-9.6.1\lib\package.conf.d

using the new-install and v1-install commands

using --overwrite-policy=always to overwrite

I'm using Windows 11. Any idea what could be my issue?

Comment: You might have installed pretty-simple.exe with something other than cabal, or a previous install crashed and left tfhe file there, just use the advice cabal gives: "Use --overwrite-policy=always to overwrite."

Comment: The error says `Use --overwrite-policy=always to overwrite.` have you tried that?

Comment: @cafce25 and Ismor, sorry I forgot to mention that I've tried that, I updated the question

Comment: did you try just manually deleting (or moving) that file?

Comment: @unhammer no actually, but surely overwriting would have solved it if that was the issue? or is there a reason you think that would help?